# Salesforce base url returning upper case URL characters

Tags: apex, knowledge, url, articles

I'm trying to publish a knowledge article in Salesforce with a REST API call by:

```
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v25.0/knowledgeManagement/articleVersions/masterVersions/'+ articleId +'?_HttpMethod=PATCH'
```

But while running, it's resolving the base URL like `https://Example.com` while its URL is `https://example.com` which is leading to unauthorised access error as it doesn't match with one described in remote site settings.
Any idea, what's happening here?

Comment: This happens if you include uppercase characters in your sandbox name. Consider using lowercase sandbox names in the future.

Comment: For now all you can do is enter all remote site settings in lower case and then convert the endpoint portion matching the remote site setting to lowercase in your code. Here is an Idea to vote for - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CNviQAG

Comment: @sfdcfox - This one is deployed on client's environment, so we don't have control over sandbox name casing.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for taking it up with salesforce and regarding lowercase suggestion, I don't have control over client's remote site settings character casing, so converting endpoint in my code to lowercase will still throw unauthorised access exception.